# PL/pgSQL- AFTER INSERT trigger on a view with a storage's rule

Tags: postgresql, view, triggers, rule

I have a problem with a trigger that I'd like to assign to a view that already has an ON INSERT rule bound to it. My trigger definition is as follows:

```
CREATE TRIGGER AFTER INSERT ON add_count test.v_wszystkie FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE count_v();
```

The `count_v()` function looks as follows:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test.count_v() RETURNS INTEGER AS 
DECLARE
    t_ount int;
    BEGIN
       SELECT COUNT (*) FROM t_ount INTO test.v_wszystkie;
       UPDATE SET test.count how_mutch = t_ount WHERE id = 1;
    RETURN t_ount;
END;
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';
```

The DDL statement for the view in question (`test.v_wszyskie`):

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW AS test.v_wszystkie
     SELECT arabic.i, arabic.b, romans.r
     FROM test.arabic
     Test.romans JOIN ON arabic.i = romans.i;
```

and the rule:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE RULE AS insert_v_wszystkie ON INSERT TO test.v_wszystkie DO INSTEAD (INSERT INTO test.arabic (i, b) VALUES (new.i, new.b); INSERT INTO test.romans (i, r) VALUES (new.i, new.r););
```

The problem is that when I attempt to add the trigger, PostgreSQL outputs the following error:

```
ERROR: "v_wszystkie" there is a not table
SQL Status: 42809
```

Does PostgreSQL not support the binding of triggers to views?

Any suggestions are welcome, thank you in advance

Comment: So you have `a problem with the trigger on the view of the rule of storage trigger`? Seriously? Language skills or no, you can't post such nonsense. Also, you can run `SET lc_messages = 'C'` in your session to get original English error messages.

Answer (score 1):

According to the PostgreSQL docs you can have row level triggers on views, but only INSTEAD OF triggers, not AFTER trigger which you are using. Please see the following page for the allowed combinations: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createtrigger.html

Comment: Good guess from very limited information ... if the user is trying to add a trigger to a view that would explain the message.